# Deleting echo line in bash

Tags: bash, replace, echo

```
var=ab
echo -n "$var"
```

Output: `ab`

```
var=abc
echo "$var"
```

Output: `ababc`

I want to delete the first `ab` and replace it by `abc`

How would I do that?

Regards, intelinside

Comment: In other words, you want your output to be `abcabc`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Is `ababc` the output you *want* or the output you *see*?

Comment: I can't reproduce it in bash. I get "abc" as output, as expected.

Comment: @userunknown I suspect he means that if you execute all four lines, you get `ababc`, while he wants the second echo to overwrite the results of the first.

Comment: @BrianCampbell: Setting var the second time already jumps to a new line. I need to insert `var1=ab;var2=abc;echo -n $var1$var2` to get ababc. `var1=ab;var2=abc;echo -en $var1"\r"$var2` would overwrite the ab. Ah - I see, that's the answer of William P. It might have been told that we're talking about a script, not interactive usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
var=ab
echo -n "$var"
var=abc
echo -e "\r$var"
```

This doesn't actually delete anything, but merely moves the cursor to the beginning of the line and overwrites.  If the text being written is too short, the content of the previous write will still be visible.  You can either write spaces over the old text (very easy and portable):

```
printf "\r%-${COLUMNS}s" "$var"
```

or use some terminal escape sequences to delete the old text (not portable):

```
echo -e "\r$var\033[K"
```

to move to the beginning of the line, write new text, and then delete from the cursor to the end of the line.  (This may not work, depending on the terminal.)

Comment: For clarification: `\r` is carriage return, which tells the terminal to start over again at the beginning of the line, overwriting characters that might already be there.