# Carrige return doesn't delete previous value

Tags: bash, return

I am trying to display some data in one terminal line. This data contains number and path to file. I'm using following code to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo
find . -type f | while read a;
do
sleep 1s;
echo -ne "$a\r";
done
```

The problem is that, actual line doesn't clear previous one. Directory contains following files `aaa.aaa`,`bbbb.bbbbb` and `cccc.cccccccccccccccc` and the output is in sequence following:

```
./cccc.cccccccccccccccc
./aaa.aaacccccccccccccc
./bbbb.bbbbbccccccccccc
```

And I want it to be:

```
./cccc.cccccccccccccccc
./aaa.aaa
./bbbb.bbbbb
```

What should I do to clear the line?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321230/deleting-echo-line-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `\033[K` after the `\r`:

```
echo -ne "$a\r\033[K";
```

That is the control sequence for erasing everything on the current line from the cursor's position until the end of the line.

Comment: @nervosol Right, my bad, that makes sense because you are outputting the new `$a` at the same time. I'm glad it helped.