# Clear line before carriage return

Tags: bash

I want to print a progress - in one line. So I use a carriage return. The problem is my progress isn't *increasing* => this means the first print could be `Processing: Foo Bar Baz` and the next print could be `Processing: Foo` . The problem with a simple carriage return is that the second print would be *overlayed* by the first print. I hope you understand what I want to say..

```
printf "\r Processing: $x"
# or
echo -en "\r Processing: $x"
```

So my question is: How can I delte the content of the current line and overwrite it with carriage return?

Comment: lookup `tput` http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html

Comment: This can help: [Deleting echo line in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10321364/1983854). It suggests using either spaces or _use some terminal escape sequences to delete the old text (not portable)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`clr_eol`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) terminal capability for this.

```
printf '\r%s Processing: %s' "$(tput el)" "$x"
```

Notice how I moved the variable out of the `printf` format string? In general do not stick variables in the format string.

Comment: If tput is not available on your system: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6774395/1808261